# Know when all servlets have been init'd?

Tags: web-services, servlets

I have a webservice like this:

- /users
- /posts
- /flags

and each one of those is a servlet, of course:

- UsersServlet.java
- PostsServlet.java
- FlagsServlet.java

they need to share a common Model (a class with a few methods that end up calling to an outside database), so I put that in another file, MyListener.java:

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        IModel model = ...
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("model", model);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and then in each servlet's init, I get that model:

```
@WebServlet("/users")
public class UsersServlet extends Servlet {
    UsersModelFacade usersModel;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        IModel model = (IModel)getServletContext().getAttribute("model");
        usersModel = new UsersModelFacade(model);
    }
    ...
}
```

but now, I don't want that "model" attribute in the servlet context to stick around, I want to removeAttribute() it.

I need to call removeAttribute() after my three servlets are done init'ing. I was hoping there would be an allServletsInitialized() method in ServletContextListener that I could override, but there is none.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Why does it matter? Why keep it there if that's not where you want it? How expensive do you think it is to retrieve from the context? Also, IIRC, it's possible a servlet could get initialized twice, even beyond if it's used for multiple mappings.

Comment: I don't want it there because it violates a lot of encapsulation; I don't want my other code to have access to the complete model, just the facade of it.

If a servlet can get init'd twice, should I move the init code into a constructor?

Comment: Then you're already violating encapsulation: move the facade construction into a utility, and keep the model there, and ignore the servlet context altogether.

Comment: I'll think about that. In the meantime, do you think there's an answer to my original question?

Comment: Wait a minute, if I move the model into a utility, wouldn't it be global at that point? I don't want to have a static IModel MyServerUtils.model, that'd be even worse for encapsulation...

As far as I can tell, servlet contexts are the best way to keep information for only the servlets, besides package-protected statics (which are gross).

Comment: Personally, I think you're fretting over nothing. Good luck!